# Count words in my string with special characters java

Tags: java, string, counting

In total there are 51 words in the string however my code returns to me 56 words which I don't understand why.

```
public class PartB
```

{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own

```
public static int countWords(String str) 
{ 
      
    // Check if the string is null 
    // or empty then return zero 
    if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) 
        return 0; 
      
    // Splitting the string around 
    // matches of the given regular 
    // expression 
    String[] words = str.split("[\\s+,'/]"); 
      
    // Return number of words 
    // in the given string 
    return words.length; 
} 

public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
      
    // Given String str 
    String str = "Sing, sing a song/Let the world sing along/" +
    "Sing of love there could be/Sing for you and for me/" +
    "Sing, sing a song/Make it simple to last/" +
    "Your whole life long/Don't worry that it's not/" +
    "Good enough for anyone/Else to hear/" +
    "Just sing, sing a song";
     
      
    // Print the result 
    System.out.println("No of words : " + 
       countWords(str)); 
}
```

}

Comment: Inspect `words` (either by setting a breakpoint or by logging it) and figure out which words are there that should not be there.

Comment: Put some effort in debugging. But a hint - Your pattern provided in the parameter of the split function is not right and hence it counts more than one word in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your `[\s+,'/]` regex:

- The `+` plus should be outside the `[ ]` character class.

  *Reason:* Without the `+`, text `"Sing, sing"` would have 2 separators, a comma and a space, with an empty token between them, and you're counting that empty token.
- The `'` apostrophe should not be there.

  *Reason:* With the `'`, text `Don't` would be 2 words, not 1.

So the regex should be: `[\s,/]+`

Changing nothing but the split call to `split("[\\s,/]+")`, the result becomes:

```
No of words : 51
```